# Increase security in tell-a-friend PHP script

Tags: php

Good day masters. I'm looking for help to increase the spam security of an old tell-a-friend PHP script I'm using. The last week it was a victim of a spam bot that use it like 60 times in less than a minute overloading the server. My question is, how I can modify it in the easiest or simplest way, maybe saving the IP or with a cookie, not sure, so that the same user can't use it more than 3 times in less than a minute for example or if you have a better suggestion, it would be more than welcome ;]

This is the HTML page that loads the script: (HTML is outdated too, I'm working on it)

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Tell a Friend</title>
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />
    <script language="javascript">
    function reset() {
        document.tellafriend.name.value="";
        document.tellafriend.email.value="";
        document.tellafriend.fmail1.value="";
        document.tellafriend.fmail2.value="";
        document.tellafriend.fmail3.value="";
    }
    function validate() {
        if (document.tellafriend.fmail1.value.length==0) {
            alert("Oops! you'll need to enter a friend's email address");
            return false;
        }
        if (document.tellafriend.email.value.length==0) {
            alert("Oops! you forget to enter your email address");
            return false;
        }
        if (document.tellafriend.name.value.length==0) {
            alert("Oops! you forgot to enter your name");
            return false;
        }
        document.tellafriend.submit()
        return true;
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body onLoad="reset()"> 
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span>Complete the details below to send this link to a friend:</span>
                <? $refurl = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; ?>
                <span><? print $refurl;?></span>
                <form name="tellafriend" action="tellafriend.php" method="post" onSubmit="return checkfields()">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                        <td> Your name*:</td>
                            <td>
                                <input name="name" size="30" maxlength="45">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Your email*:</td>
                            <td>
                                <input name="email" size="30" maxlength="45">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2">
                                <p align="center">Enter your friend's email addresses:</p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Email 1*:</td>
                            <td>
                                <input name="fmail1" class="bordesolid1" size="30" maxlength="50">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Email 2*:</td>
                            <td>
                                <input name="fmail2" size="30" maxlength="50">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Email 3*:</td>
                            <td>
                                <input name="fmail3" size="30" maxlength="50">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2">
                                <p align="center">
                                <span>This message will contain your name &amp; email address.</span><br>
                                <input onclick="validate();" type="button" value="click once to send">
                                <input type=hidden name=refurl value="<? print $refurl;?>"> 
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the PHP Script (tellafriend.php):

```
<?php
if(count($_POST)) {
    foreach(array('fmail1','fmail2','fmail3','email','name') as $key) $_POST[$key] = strip_tags($_POST[$key]);
    if(!is_secure($_POST)) {
        die("Peace People! Stop Spamming!");
    }
    $emailto = "admin@domain.com"; 
    $esubject = "Recommendation form submission"; 
    $emailtext = "$_POST[name] has used your recommendation form using an email address of $_POST[email].
    The people the recommendation has been submitted to are:
    $_POST[fmail1]
    $_POST[fmail2]
    $_POST[fmail3]
    The page recommended:
    $_POST[refurl]";
    @mail("$emailto", $esubject, $emailtext, "From: $_POST[email]");
    $thankyoupage = "thankyou.htm"; 
    $tsubject = "A web page recommendation from $_POST[name]";
    $ttext = "Hi, $_POST[name], whose email address is $_POST[email] thought you may be interested in this web page. 
    $_POST[refurl];
    @mail("$_POST[fmail1],$_POST[fmail2],$_POST[fmail3]", $tsubject, $ttext, "FROM: $_POST[email]");
    header("Location: $thankyoupage");
    exit;
}
function is_secure($ar) {
    $reg = "/(Content-Type|Bcc|MIME-Version|Content-Transfer-Encoding)/i";
    if(!is_array($ar)) {
        return preg_match($reg,$ar);
    }
    $incoming = array_values_recursive($ar);
    foreach($incoming as $k=>$v) if(preg_match($reg,$v)) return false;
    return true;
}
function array_values_recursive($array) {
    $arrayValues = array();
    foreach ($array as $key=>$value) {
        if (is_scalar($value) || is_resource($value)) {
            $arrayValues[] = $value;
            $arrayValues[] = $key;
        }
        elseif (is_array($value)) {
            $arrayValues[] = $key;
            $arrayValues = array_merge($arrayValues, array_values_recursive($value));
        }
    }
    return $arrayValues;
}
?>
```

Million thanks for your help. If someone can recommend me another (simple) one with better security it would be great too.

Comment: You should post that question here: [Code Review][1] and read [PHP security][2]  and [PHP security best practices][3]


  [1]: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119083/php-tutorial-that-is-security-accuracy-and-maintainability-conscious?lq=1
  [3]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012315/php-security-best-practices

Comment: You are best off to use social sharing tools that are already spam proof. http://www.addthis.com is a popular one.

Comment: There is no easy answer. Cookies and sessions are easily circumvented, while blocking by IP can cause problems in businesses where there are many people sharing the same public IP. You could add a captcha, but then legitimite users will be annoyed.

Comment: @pablofiumara: You can post links in comments with the link text in brackets followed by the address in parentheses.  `[Like this.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)`, for example, becomes [Like this.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say 1) you should validate that the email addresses (both sender and recipient) are valid (there are plenty of regex available to check that) - by far not bullet-proof but it's a step.

2) Simple threshold: create a DB table that tracks the IP address of the sender and the date a referral email request is submitted. Before you approve the request, check that there are not X rows in your table with the same IP in the last Y minutes

3) Add a captcha to validate that the sender is a human (requires more effort to spam)

More complex solutions would require tracking and analysing the pattern of your spammer: a lot of different IP addresses, maybe coming from certain countries you can block? Similar email addresses for many senders? Etc.